Sealed Resource is Missing for Apple Watch App
I am trying to deploy my iOS app onto the AppStore, with an Apple Watch app. However, I started to get a code signing error out of the blue. Deleting the whole WatchOS target and adding it again doesn't help. However, if deleted, the code does sign.

Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path “###.app/Watch/###.app/###” is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose “Clean All” in Xcode, delete the “build” directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing.

Tried everything that Apple suggested here.
